# Why can't list[:] be embedded in list[:].remove()?

Tags: python, list

I tried this:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
a2 = a[:]
a2.remove ('b')
print(a2)
```

And the output is

```
['a', 'c', 'd']
```

However if I remove the second line, and directly do:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
a2 = a[:].remove ('b')
print(a2)
```

The output is

```
None
```

Why is this? Why can't I embed a[:] with .remove()?
Thanks!

Comment: Hint: what happens in your first code if you replace `a2.remove ('b')` with `a2 = a2.remove ('b')`?

Comment: Isn't `a[:]` equals to `a`

Comment: the `remove` method is not implemented as being chainable. In other words, `remove` returns None. So you are assigning the results of remove to a2. Thus a2 is None.

Comment: What @RobertB said ^^ and you will find this to be true for all standard python types.. methods that have no value to return, return None.. not self... so you have got to use a variable and put them on separate lines of code.  That plus the inability to assign and compare in the same expression is enough to drive an old school c programmer crazy.  But I've resigned myself to it.

Answer (score 6):

`a[:].remove ('b')` removes `b` from `a[:]` and returns `None`, it doesn't return the list with `b` removed, that's why it has to be called in a separate line.

Answer (score 2):

To better understand this, you should look at the following:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
a2 = a.remove('b')
print(a2)
```

From documentation for `remove()`:

> Remove the first item from the list whose value is x. It is an error if 
>       there is no such item.

Thus, when you remove an element, and since `remove()` doesn't return the list, you select all the elements (`a[:]`), and set the variable `a2` to a return value  of `None` by removing an element, explaining the output.